# How to run un-greedy regex from left to right

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string that I want to match:

```
"data data and some stuff in the middle that can change, data data"
```

Now, if I want to pick up "data" at the end of the string only one time, I use a lazy quantifier:

```
data\s.+?data
```

which matches:

```
"data data and some stuff in the middle that can change, data"
```

How do I do the same thing going left to right, so I only pick up "data" at the start of the string once?

I'm using Python flavor in case anyone needs to know.

Comment: What's the output you want? `data and some stuff in the middle that can change, data`?

Comment: Yes, that is the output I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to go. The first is using capturing groups:

```
^\s*(?:data\s+)*(data\s.*?data)
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/XXqAW1/1)

What you need is in first capturing  group. The second is replacing repeated `data`s  with one `data` at both ends using:

```
^(?:\s*data)+|(data\s*)+$
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/r8N4vt/1)